# convert raw query in laravel eloquent way

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

How to convert this query in Laravel eloquent way?

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status=1  and now() BETWEEN start_time and end_time ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

// What so far i have tried 

Post::whereStatus(1)->orderBy('id','desc')->get()
```

> "and now() BETWEEN start_time and end_time" .I am unable to convert
>   this part in eloquent way.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same semantic by defining that your `start_time` is lower than the current datetime and your `end_time` is greater than it:

```
Post::whereStatus(1)
         ->where("start_time", "<", Carbon::now())
         ->where("end_time", ">", Carbon::now())
         ->orderBy('id','desc')
         ->first();
```

Comment: instead of get you can write first since he wants to limit by 1

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
Post::where('status', 1)
    ->where('start_time', '>', Carbon::now())
    ->where('end_time', '<', Carbon::now())
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->take(1)
    ->get();
```